# How to add custom form before "add to cart" page

Tags: e-commerce, magento-1.7, magento

I am using Magento 1.7. I need to get input from user so how to add custom form for taking input from user.

Let me explain: when click on any product it display product information. Now there should be a button.On click that button it should show custom form. After submit that form it should redirect to "add to cart" page with all the details of that product and values of custom form fields which is filled by user.

Is there any extension or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

On zennioptical.com the  "ORDER" button is located on the product listing template

> magento template : /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

The prescription form is actually shown on the product detail page

> magento template : /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

To accomplish this in magento create a simple product the add custom option for ('Prescription Type' etc) then you will need to do some custom css and javascript to accomplish that layout

Comment: prescription form is not showing on product detail page.It is showing after product detail page.When click on any product it shown a popup window with product detail page after that when we click on ORDER button then it show prescription form.

Comment: I used custom option method but then these fields shown on product detail page.I need first "product list" page then "product detail" page then "prescription form" then "add to cart" page.

Comment: Is this page a product detail or prescription form page - http://www.zennioptical.com/414814-metal-alloy-full-rim-frame-with-spring-hinges.html?nav_cat_id=2 ?

Comment: Don't know but most probably it is prescription form because product detail page is shown in popup window after click on product.

Comment: That page is the product detail page... the other page after is the view cart page

Comment: Whatever it is,Now I want to add this functionality that when i click on any product then a popup window come then when i click on ORDER button then prescription form should be shown after fill that form it should redirect to add to cart page and all details should be there.Now please explain how i do this ?

Comment: I searched it from very long time now you are the only hope for me.Please help.

Comment: Without seeing a markup of what your tying to do, it going to be very hard to point you in the right direction. But if you create a fresh magento install... add a product and add custom option to it, you will achieve a similar behavior to the site you mention